1D Wave Equation Rigor Question
Suppose we want to solve the following wave equation:   \begin{cases}
      u_{tt}  = c^2 u_{xx} \text{  for  } 0 < x < 1, t > 0   \\
             u(x, 0) = x(1-x) \text{  for  } 0<x<1 \\ 
u_t(x, 0) = 0\text{  for  } 0<x<1 \\
u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 \text{  for  } t>0
   \end{cases}
It's easy to get the solution via separation of variables $$u(x, t) = \sum_{k \text{ odd }} \frac{8}{k^3 \pi^3} \sin (k \pi x) \cos (c k \pi t) = \sum_{k \text{ odd }} \frac{4}{k^3 \pi^3}  \left[ \sin k \pi (x+ct) + \sin k \pi (x-ct) \right].$$
It's not hard to see that with the power of $k^3$ in the denominator, you can use standard results in Fourier analysis to be able to termwise differentiate once in both x and t variables.
What seems problematic is two derivatives (either in $x$ or $t$) for $x \pm ct = n$ for an integer $n$ for the following reason (focusing on two $x$ derivatives for convenience):  by Dirichlet's test it's easy to see that  $$\sum_{k \text{ odd }} \frac{4}{k \pi}  \left[ \sin k \pi (x+ct) + \sin k \pi (x-ct) \right] $$ converges uniformly away from $x \pm ct = n$ for an integer $n$ since the sum $$\sum_{\substack{k \text{ odd  }} \\  k \leq N}   \left[ \sin k \pi (x+ct) + \sin k \pi (x-ct) \right]$$  is easily seen to be bounded uniformly in $N$ and $x$ away from $x \pm ct = n$ for an integer $n$, and there's a classical result that (more or less) says that you can termwise differentiate when the derivatives uniformly converge.
So the question is twofold:  Is $u(x, y)$ actually classically twice differentiable at $x \pm ct = n$ for an integer $n$ (vs only once classically differentiable and once weakly differentiable, presumably)?  If not (and I suspect not), what is the physical meaning here?

I'm dumb, and this has a trivial answer.  Clearly by trig, $u(x, t)$ is the Fourier series of $\frac12 (f(x+ct) - f(x-ct))$ (as should be via D'Alembert's solution) where $f$ is the odd periodic extension of $f(x) = x(1-x)$ on $(0, 1)$.
So while one derivative is fine, two derivatives is clearly problematic at the points $x \pm ct = n$ for $n$ an integer.
